# Syncfusion Pie chart error

Tags: c#, pie-chart, syncfusion

I have a requirement to make a pie chart. I Used syncfusion and registered in the .aspx page and used library in the .aspx.cs page. While i tried to run it showing error. How can i solve it?
[image]

My .aspx code:

```
        <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" 
         MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/MasterPage.master" 
        AutoEventWireup="true" 
        CodeBehind="MasterReport.aspx.cs" 
        Inherits="AHS.LegalLink.UI.MasterReport" %>

  <%@ Register Assembly="Syncfusion.Shared.Web, Version=6.403.0.15, 
   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89"
   Namespace="Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Shared" TagPrefix="syncfusion" 
    %>
    <%@ Register Assembly="Syncfusion.Grid.Grouping.Web, Version=6.403.0.15, 
    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89"
     Namespace="Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Grid.Grouping" 
      TagPrefix="syncfusion" %>
      <%@ Register Assembly="Syncfusion.Tools.Web, Version=6.403.0.15, 
       Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89"
      Namespace="Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Tools" TagPrefix="syncfusion" 
      %>
      <%@ Register Assembly="Syncfusion.Shared.Web, Version=6.403.0.15, 
      Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89"
      Namespace="Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Shared" 
      TagPrefix="syncfusion" 
       %>
      <%@ Register Assembly="Syncfusion.Shared.Web, Version=6.403.0.15, 
       Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89"
      Namespace="Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Shared" 
       TagPrefix="syncfusion" %>
       <%@ Register Assembly="Syncfusion.Chart.Web, Version=6.403.0.15, 
        Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89"
         Namespace="Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Chart" 
         TagPrefix="syncfusion" %>
```

```
     <td class="LabelCol">
                     <syncfusion:ChartWebControl ID="mastReportChart" runat="server" Width="550px" Height="350px"
                                ChartArea-BackColor="Blue">
                                <Legend Style="position: absolute; display: block; left: 0px; top: 10px; width: 77px;
                                    height: 28px; z-index: 300;"></Legend>
                                <ToolBar Caption="ToolBar">
                                </ToolBar>
                                <%--<PrimaryXAxis LineType-BackColor="Pink" />--%>
                               <ChartArea TextRenderingHint="SystemDefault" ID="ChartArea31" BackColor="Brown">
                                    <ChartAreaMargins Bottom="0" Right="20"></ChartAreaMargins>
                                    <ChartPlotAreaMargins Bottom="0" Right="20"></ChartPlotAreaMargins>
                            </ChartArea>
                       </syncfusion:ChartWebControl>
                </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

My code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
 using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
 using AHS.LegalLink.BO;
 using Syncfusion.Web.UI;
 using Syncfusion.Drawing;
using Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Chart;
 using Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Chart;
  using Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Shared;
   using AHS.Core;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using AHS.Web.Core;



  namespace AHS.LegalLink.UI
     {
       public partial class MasterReport : BasePage
       {

      #region page events
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            InitializeControlBar();
        }

  #endregion
  #region methods
    public void InitializeControlBar()
    {

        this.mastReportChart.Legend.Visible = true;

        this.mastReportChart.BorderAppearance.FrameThickness = new Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Chart.ChartThickness(1F, 1F, 2F, 2F);
        this.mastReportChart.BorderAppearance.Interior.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        this.mastReportChart.BorderAppearance.Interior.Width = 1F;
        this.mastReportChart.BorderAppearance.SkinStyle = ChartBorderSkinStyle.Frame;
        this.mastReportChart.BorderAppearance.BaseColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(209)))), ((int)(((byte)(220)))), ((int)(((byte)(231)))));

        this.mastReportChart.BackInterior = new Syncfusion.Drawing.BrushInfo(Syncfusion.Drawing.GradientStyle.Vertical, System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(224)))), ((int)(((byte)(193))))), System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(242)))), ((int)(((byte)(226))))));
        this.mastReportChart.ChartArea.BackInterior = new Syncfusion.Drawing.BrushInfo(Syncfusion.Drawing.GradientStyle.Vertical, System.Drawing.Color.Transparent, System.Drawing.Color.Transparent);
        this.mastReportChart.ChartInterior = new Syncfusion.Drawing.BrushInfo(Syncfusion.Drawing.GradientStyle.Horizontal, System.Drawing.Color.Transparent, System.Drawing.Color.Transparent);
        this.mastReportChart.BorderAppearance.SkinStyle = ChartBorderSkinStyle.Emboss;


        this.mastReportChart.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        this.mastReportChart.ElementsSpacing = 0;


        this.mastReportChart.AutoTempFileCleanUp = true;
        this.mastReportChart.OutputFormat = ImageProviderOutputFormat.DiskFile;

        DataSet ds = new AgreementCollection().LoadAllMasterReportData(Convert.ToDateTime(ddcFromDate.Text), Convert.ToDateTime(ddcToDate.Text));

           ChartSeries series1 = new ChartSeries("LegalLink");
           series1.Type = ChartSeriesType.Pie;
            series1.ConfigItems.PieItem.LabelStyle = ChartAccumulationLabelStyle.Inside;
            series1.ConfigItems.PieItem.PieWithSameRadius = true;
            this.mastReportChart.Series.Add(series1);

            for (int i = 0; i < series1.Points.Count; i++)
                series1.Styles[i].Border.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Solid;

            double xValue = 0;
            foreach (DataRow myRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                double totala = Convert.ToInt32(myRow["Total"]);
                double totalna = Convert.ToInt32(myRow["Department"]);
                series1.Points.Add(xValue, totala);
                xValue++;
                series1.Points.Add(xValue, totalna);
                series1.Styles[0].Text = "(Amend," + series1.Points[0].YValues[0] + "%)";
                series1.Styles[1].Text = "Renew";


            }
            series1.Style.DisplayText = true;
            series1.LegendItem.Visible = true;
            series1.LegendName = "MyLedgend";

            ChartLegendItem item1 = new ChartLegendItem();

            item1.Text = "Amend:" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Amend"].ToString() + " mn"; ;
            item1.ItemStyle.TextColor = Color.DarkMagenta;
            item1.ItemStyle.ShowSymbol = true;
            item1.ItemStyle.Symbol.Color = Color.AliceBlue;
            item1.ItemStyle.Interior = new BrushInfo(GradientStyle.Horizontal, color2);
            item1.ItemStyle.Symbol.Shape = ChartSymbolShape.Cross;

            ChartLegendItem item2 = new ChartLegendItem();

            item2.Text = "Renew:" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Renew"].ToString() + " mn";
            item2.ItemStyle.TextColor = Color.DarkMagenta;
            item2.ItemStyle.ShowSymbol = true;
            item2.ItemStyle.Symbol.Color = Color.AliceBlue;
            item2.ItemStyle.Interior = new BrushInfo(GradientStyle.Horizontal, color3);
            item2.ItemStyle.Symbol.Shape = ChartSymbolShape.Cross;


            this.mastReportChart.Legend.CustomItems = new ChartLegendItem[] { item1, item2 };
            // Adding it into chart legend
            #endregion

            this.mastReportChart.Text = "LegalLink";
            // this.TargetVSSavingGraph.Font.Bold = true;

            this.mastReportChart.TextAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            this.mastReportChart.Series[0].ConfigItems.PieItem.PieType = ChartPieType.None;
            this.mastReportChart.Series[0].ConfigItems.PieItem.FillMode = ChartPieFillMode.AllPie;
            this.mastReportChart.Series[0].ConfigItems.PieItem.HeightByAreaDepth = false;
            this.mastReportChart.Series[0].ConfigItems.PieItem.HeightCoeficient = 0.1f;
            //this.mastReportChart.Series[0].PrepareStyle += new ChartPrepareStyleInfoHandler(series_PrepareStyle);

    }
    private void series_PrepareStyle(object sender, ChartPrepareStyleInfoEventArgs args)
    {
        ChartSeries series = sender as ChartSeries;
        if (series != null)
        {

            if (series.Points[args.Index].YValues[0] > 200)
            {
                args.Style.Interior = new Syncfusion.Drawing.BrushInfo(GradientStyle.Vertical, Color.Green, Color.Green);
                args.Style.Border.Color = Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                args.Style.Interior = new Syncfusion.Drawing.BrushInfo(GradientStyle.Vertical, Color.Red, Color.Red);
                args.Style.Border.Color = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We have analyzed the query. We have tried to replicate the reported scenario with the provide code snippet and unfortunately we were unable to replicate it, we suspect that assemblies were not referred properly in web.config file at your end. We have prepared a sample, in which we have rendered pie chart with respect to your code snippet. Since we are not aware of your data source, we have given random data to the chart and rendered it. Follow the below steps to render the chart.

Dll’s that are required to renderer the chart control are listed below.

- Syncfusion.Core.dll
- Syncfusion.Chart.Base.dll
- Syncfusion.Chart.Web.dll
- Syncfusion.Shared.Base.dll
- Syncfusion.Shared.Web.dll
- Syncfusion.Tools.Web.dll

And then add the following namespace in the Web.config file.

```
<configuration> 
  <system.web> 
    <compilation > 
      <assemblies> 
        <add assembly="Syncfusion.Chart.Web" /> 
        <add assembly="Syncfusion.Chart.Base" /> 
        <add assembly="Syncfusion.Shared.Web" /> 
        <add assembly="Syncfusion.Tools.Web" /> 
        <add assembly="Syncfusion.Shared.Base" /> 
        <add assembly="Syncfusion.Core" /> 
      </assemblies> 
    </compilation> 
  </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

Add the handlers in Web.config file to render the chart in web page.

```
<handlers> 
      <add name="syncfusion_generate" path="syncfusion_generate.ashx" verb="*"  
                type="Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Chart.ChartWebHandler,Syncfusion.Chart.Web"/> 
</handlers>
```

Sample for reference can be find from below.

[Sample Link](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/181724/ze/sample119673037)

Screenshot: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOUnB.png)

Since we are not aware of your exact scenario on which the issue is reproduced, we would like to know the following details, so that we can provide you the solution  sooner.

- Modify the attached sample or provide your sample with replication steps.
- Current version of Essential Studio you are using.

For more information on installation, kindly follow the below link.

[Help Documnet](https://help.syncfusion.com/aspnet-classic/chart/installation-and-deployment)

Thanks, 
Dharani.